# Python Как удалить из файла все строки с 1 символом?

Tags: python

После того как пропарсил сайт с помощью Scrapy у меня получился файл в который как то попали пустые строки и запятые

```
'url1'
запятая
'url5'
```

Вопрос - как удалить все строки с 1 символом(запятой в данном случае) что бы вышло

`'url1'`

`'url2'`

?

Comment: То есть `'url1','url5'` -> `'url1''url5'` так?

Comment: Удалить строки или удалить запятые из строк, а строки оставить пустыми?

Comment: Символ перевода строки - тоже символ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
    if len(line) == 1:
        print() # если нужна пустая строка, иначе заменить на pass
    else:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что искал =)